Children's TV show with a brother and sister, giant worms and glowing stones
Does anyone remember a children's TV show (not a cartoon) from the 80's. I'm pretty sure it was a brother and sister and they went under an ocean or a lake through jelly like consistency tunnels. 
They were chased by giant slugs or worms or something and the sister had a red glowing stone and the boy had a blue glowing stone. In one episode the boy dropped his stone and it stopped glowing at a crucial moment. I think it was British.
Does anyone know the name of this TV show?

Related question:  http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/13210/man-gives-boy-and-girl-an-egg-which-begins-to-grow-warm/13258#13258

It is Under the Mountain,  a TV miniseries from New Zealand (1981). 

The show focuses on twins Rachel and Theo Matheson. While on school summer holidays in Auckland, they are contacted by a man named Mr. Jones, who had met them briefly eight years earlier. This time, Mr. Jones reveals his true identity and mission. He is an alien, sent from another world in a battle against another race of aliens. These latter creatures were a family of slimy, slug-like beasts who could take on human form. [...]
In the final episode of the series, the twins are each required to throw a stone and focus their psychic energy into the stone to create a red and blue bridge-like construct that will defeat the [aliens].

The first part of episode 1 can be found here.

This could well be correct, but could you add some more details (maybe a quote from the script? A link to YouTube showing a relevant clip?) to support your answer.

@Andrew I was on it. Not too skilled with my phone :)

Yeah that's it! Seems like a lifetime ago since I last saw this. Thanks @Rober :D
